# I keep getting SIGTSTP error for my code but I am not able to figure out where is my code going out of bounds

Tags: c++

I am trying to find the largest sum for the difference between 3 numbers in a given list inputed by the user but I keep getting SIGTSTP and I am not able to understand where my code in going out of bounds.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int t,n,z;
    vector<long long int> a;
    long long int max,min,k,x,sum;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        cin>>n;
        while(n--){
            cin>>x;
            a.push_back(x);
        }
     max = *max_element(a.begin(),a.end());
     min = *min_element(a.begin(),a.end());
    
     int i=0,k=0;
     //to find a element other than minimum or maximum element and assign it to k
     while(i<3){
         if(a[i]==max || a[i]==min)
           continue;
         else
          k=a[i];
        i++;
     }
     if(k==0)
      k=a[0];
     //sum
     sum = abs(max-min) + abs(k-min) + abs(max-k);
     cout<<sum;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input given:

```
3
3
2 7 5
3
3 3 3
5
2 2 2 2 5
```

Comment: What input are you giving the code?

Comment: 3
3
2 7 5
3
3 3 3
5
2 2 2 2 5

Comment: @Himanshu The `i++;` you added is not always executed, because you have a `continue;` that skips over it.

Comment: Why do not you use for-loop? If the first number is less than 3, you will get UB again.

Comment: yes that was it

Answer (score 0):

```
 int i=0,k=0;
 while(i<3){
     if(a[i]==max || a[i]==min)
       continue;
     else
      k=a[i];
 }
```

You set `i` to zero when you enter the loop. The loop will not exit so long as `i` is less than 3. But nothing in the loop changes the value of `i`. So `i` will always be less than 3 and the loop will never exit.

Learn to do some basic troubleshooting such as using a debugger or adding logging.

Also, there are no comments in this code. I have no idea what this loop is supposed to do, so can't give you specific suggestions on how to fix it.

Comment: sorry that was silly indeed but i updated i value and am still getting the same error

Comment: @Himanshu Umm, you still aren't. And did you ignore the advice to use a debugger or add logging?